# go: errors parsing go.mod: /app/go.mod:3: invalid go version '1.21.3': must match format 1.23 Появляется такая ошибка кто знает помогите пожалуйста

Tags: golang, dockerfile, mod

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]go: errors parsing go.mod:
/app/go.mod:3: invalid go version '1.21.3': must match format 1.23
Появляется такая ошибка
кто знает помогите пожалуйста

Comment: скинь свой go.mod

Comment: у тебя какая версия go установлена? как вариант  на  твой машине установлена поздняя версия  чем указано в mod

Comment: go version go1.21.3 linux/amd64
эта

Comment: думаю это проблема в твоем модуле github.com/garyburd/redigo как посмотрел он использует  версию 1.17 и это ломает твою сборку. можно попробовать поставить себе  версию go 1.17

Comment: а как это сделать, подскажи пожалуйста

Comment: https://go.dev/doc/manage-install

Comment: спасибо большое, сейчас буду пробовать

Comment: Путь `/app/go.mod` наводит на подозрение, что вы собираете ваше приложение внутри контейнера docker. Какая версия `go` в контейнере?

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `go 1.21.3` напишите `go 1.21`...

Comment: go: downloading github.com/garyburd/redigo v1.6.4
так начинает ругаться

Comment: внутри контейнера, кажется 1,18, но я не знаю как установить последнюю версию внутри

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, добавив в него содержимое Dockerfile. Но вероятнее всего вам нужно заменить образ, из которого собирается контейнер, на более современный. Например, поменяв директиву `FROM` на `FROM golang:1.21.3` или `FROM golang:1.21.3-alpine`, в зависимости от того, какой образ используется в вашем контейнере сейчас.

Comment: у меня стоит FROM ubuntu:23.04  и там ниже RUN apt-get install golang -y. Ну и другие команды в этом же Dockerfile. Я попробовала как вы сказали прописать, вместо ubuntu:23.04, написала golang:1.21.3

Answer (score 0):

у тебя скорее вместо этого

```
module helloworld

go 1.21.3
```

вот это

```
module helloworld

go 1.23
```

Comment: я и так и так пробовала

Answer (score 0):

Как мы установили, у вас сборка выполняется в контейнере, в котором компилятор go версии 1.18

Поэтому вам в `go.mod` нужно написать именно ту версию, которая установлена в контейнере, или меньшую. Версия go в `go.mod` задаёт минимальную версию компилятора, которым можно собирать ваш проект. Неудивительно, что `go` в контейнере не в силах собрать проект с версией `1.21`.

Измените в текстовом редакторе `go.mod`, напишите в строке с версией `go`

```
go 1.18
```

Comment: попробовала, но при таком варианте перестает работать подключенный пакет _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql", а когда пишу версию 1,23 он снова работает

Comment: @марина покажите ваш докер файл. В нем нужно поменять версию образа, из которого вы собираете контейнер. Ну или установить в нем перед сборкой более современную версию го

Comment: не нужно, у меня получилось отладить, вроде работает, спасибо большое вам

Answer (score 0):

короче, надо было там же в консоли где я прописывала go mod init backend, go get github.com/garyburd/redigo, прописать еще go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql. Т.к. я этот пакет прописывала в ручную в самом коде, видимо он не работал. Надеюсь все не ляжет снова. Спасибо всем кто пытался помочь